# Protocol to measure light transmittance of glass (for visible wavelengths)?

Tags: visible-light, measurements

Which are common protocols to measure the light transmittance of glass (example: a window)?

I have searched for references and officials standards without success.

Which tools can be used to achieve this measurement ?

Comment: Thanks @EdV, I think you can post an answer with this. Note: my context is: I've had new windows installed at home, and I have the feeling the light transmittance % is not as high as advertised (comparison with other new windows from another manufacturer in the same house). How could I factually prove it? Which repeatable light source can I use to do the measurements ?